# Group not displayed in "Recipients" field in a mailing after selecting it

Tags: civimail, mailing

**Steps to repro:**
When creating a new mailing (or editing a draft mailing)
Click into the Recipients field, which reveals a drop-down with list of available groups
Click on one

**Expected Result**: The selected group is displayed in the field (as a sort of a button) with an "x" allowing you to remove it from the field

**Actual result**: The field remains empty/blank, but the group has been selected as the number of estimated recipients is correct
[image: recipients field issue - group not displaying]

Any ideas re what's causing this? Chrome console reveals the following **error** 6 times: *Uncaught TypeError: id.split is not a function*
Seems to be coming from the following files:
/media/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/dyn/angular-modules.js
/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js

**Set-up:**
Joomla 3.8.3
CiviCRM 4.7.29

Thank you so much for any pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

our awesome developer resolved this as described here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21780