# Problem selecting civiMail recipients

Tags: civimail

I have two instances of civiCRM, both versions 4.7.30, both running under Joomla 3.8.5.

On one instance, I can select the recipient groups and see the items selected...
In the other instance, the Recipients box isn't behaving the same -- if I try to select groups, I don't see them in the list box afterwards, and the Recipient count always reports "No Recipients".

Both instances have public mailing lists, with positive Contact counts.

[image: Good Setup]

[image: Things are not working here]

Comment: what do you see in console? Also, try to check civicrm logs(ConfigAndLog directory) for any error recorded while updating the recipient count

Comment: Check if the resource Url and all the directory paths are configured correctly in `civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1` and `civicrm/admin/setting/path?reset=1`

Comment: same issue (as reported here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22059/group-not-displayed-in-recipients-field-in-a-mailing-after-selecting-it); Chrome console reveals the following error 6 times: Uncaught TypeError: id.split is not a function Seems to be coming from the following files: /media/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/dyn/angular-modules.js /administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js; we're working on submitting a fix

Answer (score 1):

our developer resolved this as described here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21780